# Debugging SyntaxError from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, syntaxerror

Can anybody tell me whats the syntax error in the following python command,

```
arcpy.ManageTileCache_management("H:\FV","RECREATE_ALL_TILES",”Visible”, "H:\FV\MosaicData.gdb\FVImages", "IMPORT_SCHEME", , "#", "H:FV\Bound.shp", "#", "4224470", "1128.497176")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  If you are getting a syntax error, please [edit] your question to include the full error message as text.

Comment: The full error msg is, "Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)"

Comment: Please get used to using the [edit] button to revise your question with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that you're using a double-apostrophe where you should be using quotation marks:

`”Visible”` should instead be `"Visible"`.

Another problem, pointed out by Midavalo in a comment, is that you have `, ,` and you need to specify a string there, perhaps just an empty string: `, "",`.

Comment: changed it to "Visible". It is not still working. Thanks though.

Comment: @techy you also have a `, ,` - it may want you to put an empty string `, "", `

Comment: You are right, it works now... No syntax error with arcpy.ManageTileCache_management("H:\FV","RECREATE_ALL_TILES",”"Visible", "H:\FV\MosaicData.gdb\FVImages", "IMPORT_SCHEME", " " , "#", "H:FV\Bound.shp", "#", "4224470", "1128.497176")

Comment: New problem is it wants a tiling scheme, i.e. a value for "Import_Scheme", " " , empty string does not work.  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 15656, in ManageTileCache     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000735: Import Tiling Scheme: Value is required

Comment: @techy you need to read the [help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/manage-tile-cache.htm) for the command you're using. If you use the "IMPORT_SCHEME" option, the next parameter *must* be the scheme you want to import.